# Arrayformula sum one column until this row

Tags: google-sheets, sum, array-formulas

I'm trying to make an array formula which sums up all the rows until this row.
For clarification column a will be the input and column b would be the output. I'm looking for a way to do this with an arrayformula.

a1:1  b1:1
a2:2 b2:3
a3:5 b3:8
a4:3 b4:11

I tried to use
 =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INDIRECT("F1:"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(F2:F))))) but this doesn't work.

Comment: What's the input and what's the output you're expecting?

Comment: sorry if that wasn't clear. The first column is the input the second column is the output expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP changed the question with a clarification, A different answer is submitted below:

B1:

```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(transpose(A1:A5)*--IF(row(1:5),COLUMN(A:E)<=row(1:5)),ROW(1:5)^0))
```

Comment: woow that seems really complicated. But it does work. Gonna play with it tonight. Thank you so much for all of your help :)

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
=arrayformula(sumif(row(A1:A4),"<="&row(A1:A4),A1:A4))
```

[image]

The sumif is evaluated separately for each value in the criteria part so:

In the first row of the output array you have

```
=sumif(row(A1:A4),"<=1",A1:A4)
```

giving you just the first row of column A.

In the second row of the output array you have

```
=sumif(row(A1:A4),"<=2",A1:A4)
```

giving you the sum of the first 2 rows and so on.