# ArrayFormula and sum total

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to print in column B the sum of all the previous rows of column A. Through the usual formulas this is done like this:
[image]

```
B1: = A1
B2: = A2 + B1
B3: = A3 + B2
B4: = A4 + B3
```

But I need to do this using arrayformula. I tried in A1 to enter this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A4<>"";SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW(A1:A4)))))`
(If I'm not mistaken, in the English version, instead of ";" is used ",")

But it does not work:
[image]

Tell me, please, how can I solve this problem using arrayformula?

Comment: I made a typo:
 "I tried in B1 to enter this:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @[TomSharpe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159506/arrayformula-sum-one-column-until-this-row/46164758#46164758) a while back:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(ROW(A1:A4), "<="&ROW(A1:A4), A1:A4))
```

Comment: It's works, thank you very much!

Comment: Could you explain how your formula works?
Can not understand :(

Comment: Thank you for the citation. I have added a bit of explanation to my original answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159506/arrayformula-sum-one-column-until-this-row/46164758#46164758

Comment: I again tried to understand. And I did it. Thank you again for your help!