# How to tally up amount of values in a current row and above

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm creating a spending sheet in google sheets, and I wanted to make it so the **amount after** column be the sum of **amount** value on the same row and up. I don't want to sum the entire column, because that'll just give me the entire column. How could I do this without manually hard coding every single row's equation?

```
Amount  Amount After
$500.00   $500.00
$140.00   $640.00 (Value of row 2 (without headers) and above, so row 1 and 2)
$50.00    $690.00 (Value of row 3 (without headers) and above, so row 1, 2, and 3)
$135.00
```

I'm quite new to google sheets formulas, any pointers would be helpful!

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159506/arrayformula-sum-one-column-until-this-row/46164758#46164758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `B3` cell, you can do the following:

- option A: `=B2+A3`, then you can drag it below until where you want to want the values,
- option B: `=if(len(A3:A),B2+A3,)` then you can drag until the end, and if the cell next to B have any number, it will automatically sum:

[image]

To drag, click on the lower right corner of a cell and drag it down with the mouse, or select the first cell you want to drag, then select the other cells you want to drag to, and then press: `CTRL+D`

[image]