# SUMIF with ARRAYFORMULA, Argument must be range error

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to do a modified version of this formula (copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159506/arrayformula-sum-one-column-until-this-row/46164758#46164758)).

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(ROW(D1:D10), "<=" & ROW(D1:D10), D1:D10))
```

But when I changed it to

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(ROW(D1:D10), "<=" & ROW(D1:D10), IF(D1:D10 <= 50, D1:D10 * 2, D1:D10)))
```

It gave me a bunch of N/A "Argument must be a range" error.

I know I could use a helper column for the IF part, but is it possible to do this without one?

| Column D | Expected output |
| --- | --- |
| 17 | 34 |
| 63 | 97 |
| 78 | 175 |
| 25 | 225 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(D1:D="",,MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(D1:D)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(D1:D)))*
 IF(D1:D<50, D1:D*2, D1:D)), SIGN(D1:D)))
```

[image]